# Django batch process due to small memory?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that has a very large number of instances, and the memory cannot hold them.

Now I need to load them and modify some attributes with some very complex function (so I cannot perform the modification on the database directly)

I am wondering if there is any way I can batch process the queryset. For example, I can read them such as:

```
Company.objects.all()[0:1000]
Company.objects.all()[1000:2000]
Company.objects.all()[3000:3000]
...
```

until a queryset is found to be `None`. However, the above queryset will always read from beginning, which is not very efficient.

Any idea on how to batch process the model more efficiently?

Comment: When you run your second line `Company.objects.all()[1000:2000]`, Django will only fetch items 1000-2000 (zero indexed) from the database. What do you mean by "the above queryset will always read from beginning"?

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for pointing it out :). I think I misunderstood how list slices work with Django then.